# Is the set of sum of Linearly independent equations are linearly independent with the equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

If I have a set of linearly independent equations, E1, E2, ..., En. I am wondering if all the possible sums are linearly independent between them and between the original equations.

{E1, E2, .., En, E1+E2, E1+E3, E2+E3, ..., Ei+En}
are linearly independent?

If yes, how can I prove it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course not (unless $n=1$). Since your set contains $E_1$, $E_2$ and $E_1+E_2$, it cannot be linearly independent, because$$1\times E_1+1\times E_2+(-1)\times(E_1+e_2)=0.$$

Comment: Thank you, and what about this set of equations? 
{E1, E1+E2, E1+E3, E1+E4} are they linearly independent? How do I prove this?

Comment: @gen *Which* set of equations?

Comment: Sorry I edited my comment. Thanks.

Comment: @gen That's another question. If you want to ask that question, ask it as a separate question. And if my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as your accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help. I've asked a new question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2460334/sum-of-linearly-independent-equations