# Sum of Linearly independent equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a set of linearly independent equations, E1, E2, ..., En. Is the following set of equations linearly independent?

{E1, E1+E2, E1+E3, ..., E1+En}

If yes, how can I prove it? Thanks.

Comment: yes it's true, prove it by contradiction.

Comment: What does it mean for equations to be linearly independent? (inspired by the comment of 5xum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If$$\alpha_1E_1+\alpha_2(E_1+E_2)+\alpha_3(E_1+E_3)+\cdots+\alpha_n(E_1+E_n)=0,$$then$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\cdots+\alpha_n=0\\\alpha_2=0\\\alpha_3=0\\\cdots\\\alpha_n=0\end{array}\right.$$and therefore all $\alpha_k$'s are equal to $0$.

Comment: Since $E_i$ are equations, this is a pretty weird notation...

Comment: @5xum Yes, I know. But it seems to be a natural notation for the OP.

Comment: If $E_i$ are equations they all need to have 0 in the RHS right. I think the question won't make sense otherwise.

Comment: I assumed that the RHS was $0$.

Comment: Thank you for help and sorry for the ambiguity, I am considering a system of linear equations where the RHS equal to zero.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If equations $E_1, E_2, E_3, ... , E_n$ are linearly independent it means that $$a_1 E_1 +a_2 E_2 + ...+a_nE_n=0\hspace{0.5cm}\mathrm{iff}\hspace{0.5cm}a_i=0 \hspace{0.5cm}\forall\hspace{0.5cm}i\in\{1..n\}$$

For the set of equations you have same thing must be true if they are independent. Therefore
$$b_1 E_1 +b_2 (E_1+E_2) + ...+b_n(E_1+E_n)=0$$
This can be rewritten as the first equation, for which any constant the satisfy this are all $0$

Hence the set of equations are independent.

This a common result in linear algebra. **Any linear combination of linearly independent vectors is linearly independent.**